# Upgraded to SQL Server 2017 and now see WSFC lease timeouts

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, sql-server-2017

I recently upgraded a production DB environment from SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition to 2017 Enterprise Edition (CU3). We used a Basic Availability Group when on Standard Edition and recreated the AG's on 2017 Enterprise after the in-place upgrade of SQL Server.

After the upgrade, we have had several instances where the SQL Server log shows that the Windows Server Failover Cluster WSFC lease times out. As a result, our apps referencing the AG via the listener lose momentary connection.

The screenshot below is of our SQL Server log starting with the first message at the bottom

> Error: 19421, Severity: 16, State:1.

Error rows were written through 11:01:17am indicating that everything was back in a normal state within 7 seconds:

[image]

The two SQL Servers in this AG are running on Windows Server 2012R2. Nothing about the Windows Server Failover Cluster knowingly changed during the SQL Server upgrade, and we did not have this issue prior to the upgrade.

Could there be an underlying issue with the SQL Server engine? Or does this point to an issue with WSFC? Any pointers you can provide will be greatly appreciated!

Update on 3/15 - Adding Cluster logs from PS command Get-ClusterLog -UseLocalTime during incident period.

```
 00006670.000045b0::2018/03/12-11:01:10.150 ERR   [RES] SQL Server Availability Group <AG_Membership>: [hadrag] Lease renewal failed because the existing lease is no longer valid.
00006670.000045b0::2018/03/12-11:01:10.151 ERR   [RES] SQL Server Availability Group <AG_Membership>: [hadrag] The lease is expired. The lease should have been renewed by 2018/03/12-16:01:00.068
000027d4.00001804::2018/03/12-11:01:10.203 INFO  [GUM] Node 1: executing request locally, gumId:44530, my action: /dm/update, # of updates: 1
000027d4.00001804::2018/03/12-11:01:10.219 INFO  [GUM] Node 1: executing request locally, gumId:44531, my action: /dm/update, # of updates: 1
000027d4.00001804::2018/03/12-11:01:10.463 INFO  [RCM] rcm::RcmApi::FailResource: (AG_Membership)
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:10.464 INFO  [RCM] HandleMonitorReply: FAILURENOTIFICATION for 'AG_Membership', gen(4) result 0/0.
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:10.464 INFO  [RCM] Res AG_Membership: Online -> ProcessingFailure( StateUnknown )
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:10.464 INFO  [RCM] TransitionToState(AG_Membership) Online-->ProcessingFailure.
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:10.464 INFO  [RCM] rcm::RcmGroup::UpdateStateIfChanged: (AG_Membership, Online --> Pending)
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:10.464 ERR   [RCM] rcm::RcmResource::HandleFailure: (AG_Membership)
000027d4.00002508::2018/03/12-11:01:10.464 INFO  [RCM] ignored non-local state Pending for group AG_Membership
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:10.464 INFO  [RCM] resource AG_Membership: failure count: 1, restartAction: 2 persistentState: 1.
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:10.464 INFO  [RCM] numDependents is zero, auto-returning true
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:10.464 INFO  [RCM] Greater than restartPeriod time has elapsed since first failure of AG_Membership, resetting failureTime and failureCount.
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:10.464 INFO  [RCM] Will queue immediate restart (500 milliseconds) of AG_Membership after terminate is complete.
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:10.464 INFO  [RCM] Res AG_Membership: ProcessingFailure -> WaitingToTerminate( DelayRestartingResource )
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:10.464 INFO  [RCM] TransitionToState(AG_Membership) ProcessingFailure-->[WaitingToTerminate to DelayRestartingResource].
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:10.464 INFO  [RCM] Res AG_Membership: [WaitingToTerminate to DelayRestartingResource] -> Terminating( DelayRestartingResource )
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:10.464 INFO  [RCM] TransitionToState(AG_Membership) [WaitingToTerminate to DelayRestartingResource]-->[Terminating to DelayRestartingResource].
00006670.0000194c::2018/03/12-11:01:10.465 WARN  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] Lease timeout detected, logging perf counter data collected so far
00006670.0000194c::2018/03/12-11:01:10.465 WARN  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] Date/Time, Processor time(%), Available memory(bytes), Avg disk read(secs), Avg disk write(secs)
00006670.0000194c::2018/03/12-11:01:10.465 WARN  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] 3/12/2018 16:0:21.0, 95.167191, 1079693312.000000, 0.004913, 0.004337
00006670.0000194c::2018/03/12-11:01:10.465 WARN  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] 3/12/2018 16:0:31.0, 98.749704, 1048801280.000000, 0.013747, 0.003205
00006670.0000194c::2018/03/12-11:01:10.465 WARN  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] 3/12/2018 16:0:41.0, 91.797399, 1201926144.000000, 0.013994, 0.002175
00006670.0000194c::2018/03/12-11:01:10.465 WARN  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] 3/12/2018 16:0:51.0, 72.669750, 1377648640.000000, 0.003069, 0.001442
00006670.0000194c::2018/03/12-11:01:10.465 WARN  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] 3/12/2018 16:1:1.0, 62.595431, 1232269312.000000, 0.005762, 0.001885
00006670.0000194c::2018/03/12-11:01:10.465 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] Stopping Health Worker Thread
00006670.00002f90::2018/03/12-11:01:10.465 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] Health worker was asked to terminate
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:10.741 INFO  [RCM] rcm::RcmApi::AddPossibleOwner: (AG_Membership, 1)
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:10.741 INFO  [GUM] Node 1: executing request locally, gumId:44532, my action: /rcm/gum/AddPossibleOwner, # of updates: 1
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:10.741 INFO  [RCM] rcm::RcmGum::AddPossibleOwner(AG_Membership,1)
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:10.741 ERR   mscs::GumAgent::ExecuteHandlerLocally: (5010)' because of 'The specified node is already a possible owner.'
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:10.741 WARN  [DM] Aborting group transaction 67:67:44313+1
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:10.741 ERR   [RCM] rcm::RcmApi::AddPossibleOwner: (5010)' because of 'Gum handler completed as failed'
000027d4.0000569c::2018/03/12-11:01:10.741 INFO  [RCM] rcm::RcmApi::MoveGroup: (AG_Membership, 1, 0, MoveType::Manual )
000027d4.0000569c::2018/03/12-11:01:10.743 INFO  [RCM] rcm::RcmApi::OnlineResource: (AG_Membership, 0)
000027d4.0000569c::2018/03/12-11:01:10.743 ERR   [RCM] rcm::RcmApi::OnlineResource: (5023) because of 'The API call is not valid while resource is in the [Terminating to DelayRestartingResource] state.'
00006670.00002128::2018/03/12-11:01:10.949 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] SQLMoreResults() returns -1 with following information
00006670.00002f90::2018/03/12-11:01:10.950 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] Change diagnostics interval worker is stopped
00006670.00002128::2018/03/12-11:01:10.989 ERR   [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] ODBC Error: [HY008] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Operation canceled (0)
00006670.00002128::2018/03/12-11:01:10.989 ERR   [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] ODBC Error: [01000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]  (0)
00006670.00002128::2018/03/12-11:01:10.989 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] No more diagnostics results
00006670.00002128::2018/03/12-11:01:10.989 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] Diagnostics is stopped
00006670.00002128::2018/03/12-11:01:10.989 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] Disconnect from SQL Server
00006670.00002128::2018/03/12-11:01:11.218 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] Extended Event logging is stopped
00006670.00002128::2018/03/12-11:01:11.228 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] Extended Event target state:
00006670.00002128::2018/03/12-11:01:11.228 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] Extended Event session summary: dropped buffers = 0, dropped events = 0
00006670.0000194c::2018/03/12-11:01:11.284 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] Stopping Change Diagnostics interval Worker Thread
00006670.0000194c::2018/03/12-11:01:11.341 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group <AG_Membership>: [hadrag] Connect to SQL Server ...
00006670.0000194c::2018/03/12-11:01:11.667 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group <AG_Membership>: [hadrag] The connection was established successfully
00006670.0000194c::2018/03/12-11:01:11.688 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group <AG_Membership>: [hadrag] Disconnect from SQL Server
00006670.0000194c::2018/03/12-11:01:11.697 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group <AG_Membership>: [hadrag] Offline call successful in Terminate function
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:11.697 INFO  [RCM] HandleMonitorReply: TERMINATERESOURCE for 'AG_Membership', gen(5) result 0/0.
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:11.697 INFO  [RCM] Res AG_Membership: [Terminating to DelayRestartingResource] -> DelayRestartingResource( StateUnknown )
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:11.697 INFO  [RCM] TransitionToState(AG_Membership) [Terminating to DelayRestartingResource]-->DelayRestartingResource.
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:11.697 WARN  [RCM] Queueing immediate delay restart of resource AG_Membership in 500 ms.
000027d4.000047cc::2018/03/12-11:01:12.197 INFO  [RCM] Delay-restarting AG_Membership and any waiting dependents.
000027d4.000047cc::2018/03/12-11:01:12.197 INFO  [RCM-rbtr] giving default token to group AG_Membership
000027d4.000047cc::2018/03/12-11:01:12.197 INFO  [RCM-rbtr] giving default token to group AG_Membership
000027d4.000047cc::2018/03/12-11:01:12.198 INFO  [RCM] Res AG_Membership: DelayRestartingResource -> OnlineCallIssued( StateUnknown )
000027d4.000047cc::2018/03/12-11:01:12.198 INFO  [RCM] TransitionToState(AG_Membership) DelayRestartingResource-->OnlineCallIssued.
000027d4.0000569c::2018/03/12-11:01:12.198 INFO  rcm::RcmResource::OnlineWorker[RCM] Issuing Online(AG_Membership) to RHS.
000027d4.0000569c::2018/03/12-11:01:12.198 INFO  [RCM] HandleMonitorReply: ONLINERESOURCE for 'AG_Membership', gen(5) result 997/0.
000027d4.0000569c::2018/03/12-11:01:12.198 INFO  [RCM] Res AG_Membership: OnlineCallIssued -> OnlinePending( StateUnknown )
000027d4.0000569c::2018/03/12-11:01:12.198 INFO  [RCM] TransitionToState(AG_Membership) OnlineCallIssued-->OnlinePending.
00006670.00004048::2018/03/12-11:01:12.200 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group <AG_Membership>: [hadrag] The DeadLockTimeout property has a value of 300000
00006670.00004048::2018/03/12-11:01:12.204 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group <AG_Membership>: [hadrag] The PendingTimeout property has a value of 180000
00006670.00004048::2018/03/12-11:01:12.207 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group <AG_Membership>: [hadrag] Connect to SQL Server ...
00006670.00004048::2018/03/12-11:01:12.283 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group <AG_Membership>: [hadrag] The connection was established successfully
00006670.00004048::2018/03/12-11:01:12.331 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group <AG_Membership>: [hadrag] Current SQL Instance is not part of Failover clustering
00006670.00004048::2018/03/12-11:01:12.331 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] Starting Health Worker Thread
00006670.00005afc::2018/03/12-11:01:12.405 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] XEvent session MSSQLSERVER is created with RolloverCount 10, MaxFileSizeInMBytes 100, and LogPath 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\LOG\'
00006670.00005afc::2018/03/12-11:01:12.406 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] Extended Event logging is started
00006670.00005afc::2018/03/12-11:01:12.406 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] Health worker started for instance SQLSERVER1
00006670.00005afc::2018/03/12-11:01:12.406 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] Connect to SQL Server ...
00006670.00005afc::2018/03/12-11:01:12.410 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] The connection was established successfully
00006670.00005afc::2018/03/12-11:01:12.438 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] Diagnostics is started
00006670.00005afc::2018/03/12-11:01:12.439 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] SQL Server component 'system' health state has been changed from '' to 'clean' at 2018-03-12 11:01:12.437
00006670.00005afc::2018/03/12-11:01:12.439 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] SQL Server component 'resource' health state has been changed from '' to 'clean' at 2018-03-12 11:01:12.437
00006670.00005afc::2018/03/12-11:01:12.444 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] SQL Server component 'query_processing' health state has been changed from '' to 'clean' at 2018-03-12 11:01:12.437
00006670.00005afc::2018/03/12-11:01:12.445 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] SQL Server component 'io_subsystem' health state has been changed from '' to 'clean' at 2018-03-12 11:01:12.437
00006670.00005afc::2018/03/12-11:01:12.447 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] SQL Server component 'events' health state has been changed from '' to 'unknown' at 2018-03-12 11:01:12.437
00006670.00004e90::2018/03/12-11:01:12.449 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] Change diagnostics interval worker is started
000027d4.00001804::2018/03/12-11:01:13.066 INFO  [GUM] Node 1: executing request locally, gumId:44532, my action: /dm/update, # of updates: 1
000027d4.00001804::2018/03/12-11:01:13.101 INFO  [GUM] Node 1: executing request locally, gumId:44533, my action: /dm/update, # of updates: 1
000027d4.000047cc::2018/03/12-11:01:13.149 INFO  [RCM] rcm::RcmApi::OnlineGroup: (AG_Membership, 0)
000027d4.000047cc::2018/03/12-11:01:13.149 INFO  [GUM] Node 1: executing request locally, gumId:44534, my action: /rcm/gum/SetGroupPersistentState, # of updates: 1
000027d4.000047cc::2018/03/12-11:01:13.149 INFO  [RCM] rcm::RcmGum::SetGroupPersistentState(AG_Membership,1)
000027d4.000047cc::2018/03/12-11:01:13.149 INFO  [DM] An empty single transaction is cancelled 67:67:44315+1::0
00006670.00004048::2018/03/12-11:01:13.159 INFO  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group <AG_Membership>: [hadrag] Disconnect from SQL Server
00006670.00004048::2018/03/12-11:01:13.160 INFO  [RHS] Resource AG_Membership has come online. RHS is about to report status change to RCM
000027d4.0000569c::2018/03/12-11:01:13.161 INFO  [RCM] HandleMonitorReply: ONLINERESOURCE for 'AG_Membership', gen(5) result 0/0.
000027d4.0000569c::2018/03/12-11:01:13.161 INFO  [RCM] Res AG_Membership: OnlinePending -> Online( StateUnknown )
000027d4.0000569c::2018/03/12-11:01:13.161 INFO  [RCM] TransitionToState(AG_Membership) OnlinePending-->Online.
000027d4.0000569c::2018/03/12-11:01:13.161 INFO  [RCM] rcm::RcmGroup::UpdateStateIfChanged: (AG_Membership, Pending --> Online)
000027d4.00002508::2018/03/12-11:01:13.161 INFO  [RCM] ignored non-local state Online for group AG_Membership
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:13.161 INFO  [RCM] moved 0 tasks from staging set to task set.  TaskSetSize=0
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:13.161 INFO  [RCM] rcm::RcmPriorityManager::StartGroups: [RCM] done, executed 0 tasks
000027d4.000047cc::2018/03/12-11:01:13.163 INFO  [RCM] Group AG_Membership: done going through resources, returning true
000027d4.000047cc::2018/03/12-11:01:13.166 INFO  [RCM] rcm::RcmApi::AddPossibleOwner: (AG_Membership, 1)
000027d4.000047cc::2018/03/12-11:01:13.166 INFO  [GUM] Node 1: executing request locally, gumId:44535, my action: /rcm/gum/AddPossibleOwner, # of updates: 1
000027d4.000047cc::2018/03/12-11:01:13.166 INFO  [RCM] rcm::RcmGum::AddPossibleOwner(AG_Membership,1)
000027d4.000047cc::2018/03/12-11:01:13.167 ERR   mscs::GumAgent::ExecuteHandlerLocally: (5010)' because of 'The specified node is already a possible owner.'
000027d4.000047cc::2018/03/12-11:01:13.167 WARN  [DM] Aborting group transaction 67:67:44315+1
000027d4.000047cc::2018/03/12-11:01:13.167 ERR   [RCM] rcm::RcmApi::AddPossibleOwner: (5010)' because of 'Gum handler completed as failed'
000027d4.000047cc::2018/03/12-11:01:13.181 WARN  [RCM] AG_Membership cannot be hosted on node 2
000027d4.000047cc::2018/03/12-11:01:13.181 WARN  [RCM] Possible owners: <vector len='1'>
000027d4.000047cc::2018/03/12-11:01:13.181 WARN      <item>1</item>
000027d4.000047cc::2018/03/12-11:01:13.181 WARN  </vector>
000027d4.0000569c::2018/03/12-11:01:13.181 INFO  [GUM] Node 1: executing request locally, gumId:44535, my action: /rcm/gum/SetGroupPreferredOwners, # of updates: 1
000027d4.0000569c::2018/03/12-11:01:13.181 INFO  [RCM] rcm::RcmGum::SetGroupPreferredOwners(AG_Membership,<vector len='1'>
000027d4.0000569c::2018/03/12-11:01:13.181 INFO      <item>1</item>
000027d4.0000569c::2018/03/12-11:01:13.181 INFO  </vector>
000027d4.0000569c::2018/03/12-11:01:13.181 INFO  )
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:13.270 INFO  [GUM] Node 1: executing request locally, gumId:44536, my action: /dm/update, # of updates: 1
000047bc.00004d8c::2018/03/12-11:01:13.271 INFO  [RES] Network Name: Agent: Sending request Netname/RecheckConfig to NN:212d9bab-6bb4-4c46-8b56-20e1e60fd7ca:Netbios
000027d4.00001804::2018/03/12-11:01:15.802 INFO  [RCM] rcm::RcmApi::OnlineResource: (AG_Membership, 0)
000027d4.0000569c::2018/03/12-11:01:17.362 INFO  [GUM] Node 1: executing request locally, gumId:44537, my action: /dm/update, # of updates: 1
000027d4.0000569c::2018/03/12-11:01:17.368 INFO  [GUM] Node 1: executing request locally, gumId:44538, my action: /dm/update, # of updates: 1
000027d4.00001aac::2018/03/12-11:01:17.404 INFO  [GUM] Node 1: executing request locally, gumId:44539, my action: /dm/update, # of updates: 1
000027d4.0000569c::2018/03/12-11:01:17.411 INFO  [GUM] Node 1: executing request locally, gumId:44540, my action: /dm/update, # of updates: 1
000027d4.0000569c::2018/03/12-11:01:17.425 INFO  [GUM] Node 1: executing request locally, gumId:44541, my action: /dm/update, # of updates: 1
000027d4.0000569c::2018/03/12-11:01:17.430 INFO  [GUM] Node 1: executing request locally, gumId:44542, my action: /dm/update, # of updates: 1
000027d4.00004ce0::2018/03/12-11:01:17.436 INFO  [GUM] Node 1: executing request locally, gumId:44543, my action: /dm/update, # of updates: 1
000027d4.0000569c::2018/03/12-11:01:17.442 INFO  [GUM] Node 1: executing request locally, gumId:44544, my action: /dm/update, # of updates: 1
000027d4.00001aac::2018/03/12-11:01:17.445 INFO  [GUM] Node 1: executing request locally, gumId:44545, my action: /dm/update, # of updates: 1
000027d4.00001804::2018/03/12-11:01:17.456 INFO  [GUM] Node 1: executing request locally, gumId:44546, my action: /dm/update, # of updates: 1
000027d4.00001804::2018/03/12-11:01:17.460 INFO  [GUM] Node 1: executing request locally, gumId:44547, my action: /dm/update, # of updates: 1
000027d4.00006198::2018/03/12-11:01:17.473 INFO  [GUM] Node 1: executing request locally, gumId:44548, my action: /dm/update, # of updates: 1
000047bc.00004d8c::2018/03/12-11:01:18.272 INFO  [RES] Network Name: Agent: Sending request Netname/RecheckConfig to NN:212d9bab-6bb4-4c46-8b56-20e1e60fd7ca:Netbios
000047bc.00004d8c::2018/03/12-11:01:19.980 INFO  [RES] Network Name <AG_Membership_LISTERNER01>: Dns: HealthCheck: LISTERNER01
```

Comment: Are there any errors listed in the WSFC error log?

Comment: What's the topology of the WSFC? Has anything changed regarding the usage of the AG since the upgrade (i.e. it has gone into prod, thereby generating more traffic between the replicas)? As Max mentioned, you're going to need to check the cluster log for more detailed information. If you run get-clusterlog via an elevated Powershell prompt it will generate verbose logs for both nodes, which you can then use to determine why the lease timeout is occurring.

Comment: 1) is this a vm? 2) The error states (we don't know if it's true or not yet) that the **cluster** failed to signal SQL Server so we'll need to look at the cluster log 3) since you can't upgrade basic AGs, this had to be re-create which means resource based properties are lost. Did anything change the lease-timeout before on the cluster resource properties? 4) Can you run some perfmon collection and see if the server is under high load, incorrect MaxDOP settings (which can cause high load), etc., to see if the failures can be correlated?

Comment: I'll do some perfmon logging tomorrow and will get back asap with answers to other questions.

Yes, it is a VM. The issue occurrences are occasionally in correlation with the starting of various DB-related processes which has me thinking CPU stress could be a possibility but SysAdmins reported no issues through VM console logging.

Comment: @Dan - This is a simple, two-node cluster used for HA. The production AG came down for maintenance on a weekend then came back online after the SQL 2017 upgrade. Same traffic on the AG as before.

Thanks for the PS recommendation. This is the only thing I found from the log:

000047bc.00006eb0::2018/03/12-11:01:19.935 INFO  [RES] Network Name <AG_Membership_ListenerName>: Dns: HealthCheck: ListenerName
000047bc.00006eb0::2018/03/12-11:01:19.935 INFO  [RES] Network Name <AG_Membership_ListenerName>: Dns: End of Slow Operation, state: Initialized/Reading, prevWorkState: Reading

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this in my first reply, but the cluster log times are in UTC. So you'll need to adjust for this when trying to match up log events with the lease timeouts.

Comment: @Dan If you want the log to be in the local TZ, use Get-ClusterLog -UseLocalTime

Comment: @SeanGallardy-Microsoft thanks for the recommendation. I updated the original post with the cluster logs during the incident window.

Comment: Thanks @SeanGallardy-Microsoft. I wasn't aware of that switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the updated information, it looks like **something** ran the server out of CPU. I say something, because it could be inside of SQL Server - such as a bad parallel plan (or multiple calls of it), incorrect MaxDOP, etc. - or outside of SQL Server, we don't know from just the log what processes were taking up the most CPU.

The actual issue didn't tell us too much except that the lease was expected to be renewed about 10 seconds earlier:

> 2018/03/12-**11:01:10.151** ERR   [RES] SQL Server Availability Group : [hadrag] The lease is expired. The lease should have been renewed by 2018/03/12-**16:01:00.068**

The reason it is most likely (but not 100%, because if this is a VM it could have been over subscribed, paused for a snapshot, paused from migration, etc.) is due to the information later in the cluster log:

> Date Time              CPU%
>
> ---
>
> 3/12/2018 16:0:21.0, 95.167191
>   3/12/2018 16:0:31.0, 98.749704
>   3/12/2018 16:0:41.0, 91.797399
>   3/12/2018 16:0:51.0, 72.669750
>   3/12/2018 16:1:1.0, 62.595431

If you look, the lease timed out at 16:01:00 and the CPU usage was 92-99% the previous 30 seconds which just so happens to line up with the **default** lease timeout setting.

### Now what?

This was an upgrade from 2016 to 2017 **AND** and edition upgrade from standard to Enterprise. I'd start by investigating things like MAXDOP, database compatibility level (for the optimizer and plans), and watching to see if any queries are going parallel at eating up CPU time. My guess is it has something to do with that, otherwise it's something outside of SQL Server causing the high CPU (which you can watch in SQL Server through the ring buffer).

Comment: This is incredible analysis and points me in a good direction. I think anything I find from here is deserving of its own thread. Thank you for your help!